# что делает $crawler->addHtmlContent('<html><body /></html>')

Tags: php

у меня есть код

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;


     $crawler = new Crawler($html);

$sd = $crawler->addHtmlContent('<html><body /></html>');
var_dump($sd);
}
```

этот код выводит  Attaching DOM nodes from multiple documents in the same crawler is forbidden.что делает $crawler->addHtmlContent();

Comment: Вы думаете здесь __все__ используют Symfony и знают что `crawler` именно оттуда? В будущем потрудитесь пояснять что за `$crawler`, используете или нет вы фреймворк, и если да - то какой.

Comment: @Саркис123, укажите в тегах фреймворк, который вы используете

Answer (score 0):

Я использую фреймворк Laravel.Ошибка была в том,что надо использовать один из вариантов:`new Crawler($html); или $crawler->addHtmlContent($html);`